# Flutter PWA/web - how do I debug crash and record/report them in production? Please help me out

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, flutter-web

I have a flutter we  application. But there are some things I  totally not able to find anywhere.

How can I see flutter web runtime issues in console. And how can I log/record those issues and crashes like firebase crashalytics.

I know something about the fact that flutter code gets converted into javascript for web and thats the reason the issues dont show in ide console. But is not there any way i can see issues in console. And i know that crashalytics doesnt work for web. But is there no alternative/workaround.

Thanks